# Lagrange-Newton minimization and initial value for the Lagrange multipliers

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

**Short version.** How to choose the initial values for the Lagrange multipliers in the Lagrange-Newton
equality-constraint minimization method?

**Introduction.** The problem to solve is

\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n} f(\mathbf x) \quad \text{subject to} \quad h(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0,
\end{equation}

where $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ are twice continuously
differentiable functions.

I implemented the local Lagrange-Newton method, which aims at finding a solution
$(\mathbf x, \pmb \mu) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ of the KKT equations

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf x) + \nabla h(\mathbf x)\pmb \mu &= \mathbf 0,\\
h(\mathbf x)&= \mathbf 0,
\end{align}

where $\nabla h(\mathbf x) = (\nabla h_1(\mathbf x), \ldots, \nabla h_m(\mathbf x)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is the
Jacobi matrix of $h$ and $\pmb \mu \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the vector of Lagrange multipliers.

I need initial values $\mathbf x_0$ and $\pmb \mu_0$ in order to use Newton's method to iteratively solve
the KKT equations. Based on my application, I have a reasonable value for $\mathbf x_0$.

**Question 1** What are good general strategies for selecting $\pmb \mu_0$?

**Question 2** How about using $\mathbf x_0$
to compute $\pmb \mu_0$ as the least-squares solution of the first KKT equation:
\begin{equation}
\pmb \mu_0 = \text{arg}\min_{\pmb \mu \in \mathbb{R}^m} \|\nabla f(\mathbf x_0) + \nabla h(\mathbf x_0)\pmb \mu\|^2.
\end{equation}

For some values for $\mathbf x_0$, the least-squares solution $\pmb \mu_0$ makes the method to diverge, whereas setting $\pmb \mu_0$ to a random vector in $[-1, 1]^m$ leads to convergence to the right solution. Any thoughts on that?

**Question 3** Is it beneficial to have $\mathbf x_0$ to fulfill the constraints? Or is the distance to
the solution $(\mathbf x, \pmb \mu)$ more important?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an answer to this question in Izmailov AF, Solodov MV: Newton-Type Methods for Optimization and Variational Problems, Springer 2014, section 4.1.1. Newton-Lagrange Method, p. 208.

Here is my attempt at a derivation (in the book, the result is just given). Given the Lagrangian

$$
L(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\lambda}) 
= 
f(\mathbf{x}) + \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})
$$

we have

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
+
\boldsymbol{\lambda}^T \frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
$$

or

$$
{\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
=
{\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
+
{\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T \boldsymbol{\lambda}.
$$

In an extremum this is zero, so we have

$$
- {\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
=
{\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T \boldsymbol{\lambda}. 
$$

In the book it is assumed that

$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
$$

has full column rank, so

$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
{\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
$$

is non-singular.

If we multiply the last equation from the left by

$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
$$

(which, however, is not an invertible step, so I'm not sure here) we get

$$
- 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
{\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
=
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
{\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T 
\boldsymbol{\lambda}. 
$$

and therefore by multiplying with the inverse of the non-singular matrix on the right side, we obtain:

$$
- 
\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
{\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T\right)^{-1} 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
{\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}}^T
=
\boldsymbol{\lambda}. 
$$

Their argument is that if this equation holds for an extremum at $(\overline{\mathbf{x}}, \overline{\boldsymbol{\lambda}})$, it approximately holds at $\hat{\mathbf{x}} \approx \overline{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \approx \overline{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}$, so we can insert  $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and obtain $\hat{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}$.

Please note that gradients are row vectors in my notation.

Edit: It may actually be better to leave out the non-invertible transformation and just provide a solution based on the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse for the original equation.

I would appreciate any comments.